# Intradia google finance

Tags: python, google-api

Tengo que trabajar con los datos de google finance para hacer un modelado de datos intradia, es decir, necesito los valores cada minuto o cada cinco minutos durante un día.

Lo estoy haciendo con python con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
uri = 'http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i={period}&p={days}d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q={ticker}'.format(ticker=ticker, period=period, days=days)
page = requests.get(uri)
reader = csv.reader(page.content.splitlines())
```

de https://gist.github.com/lebedov/f09030b865c4cb142af1.

El problema es que google no me deja coger tantos datos y me da un error como este (URL de ejemplo: https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=1d&f=v&df=cpct&q=AAPL)

> We're sorry...
>
> ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To
> protect our users, we can't process your request right now. See Google
> Help for more information.

¿Alguien sabe cómo conseguir estos datos o al menos interpretar la uri para que google, al tener que darme menos datos me los de? Como solución provisional, también me podría valer descargar datos desde un .csv aunque es mas engorroso.

No necesito demasiados.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Google ha bloqueado esa API. Hace unos años existían bastantes APIs a las que se les podía preguntar "en tiempo real" (cada 10 segundos, por ejemplo) y respondían, pero la mayoría de estas APIs han pasado a ser de pago, requieren una autenticación mediante un token que obienes una vez te has registrado en su sitio, o bien han disminuido la frecuencia con que actualizan sus datos a 1 vez por hora.

Si no necesitas los datos en tiempo real, sino que te bastan los del último día, parece que esta API de Yahoo a día de hoy (2018-11-22) aún funciona:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/AAPL?&interval=1m
```

### Ampliación

Ejemplo de cómo usar `requests` para recuperar el json y `pandas` para convertirlo a una forma tratable y un gráfico.

```
import requests

url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/AAPL?&interval=1m&range=1d"
j = requests.get(url).json()

# Extraer del JSON la información relevante
tiempos = j['chart']['result'][0]['timestamp']
data = j['chart']['result'][0]["indicators"]['quote'][0]
cierre = data["close"]
apertura = data["open"]
volumen = data["volume"]
maximo = data["high"]
minimo = data["low"]

# Cargarlo en un dataframe pandas
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"cierre": cierre, "apertura": apertura,
                   "volumen": volumen, "maximo": maximo, "minimo": minimo},
                  index=pd.to_datetime(tiempos, unit='s'))
```

El dataframe tiene esta pinta (`df.head()`):

[image: Dataframe]

Si hacemos:

```
df.plot(y=["maximo", "minimo"])
```

Obtenemos:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me has salvado un trabajo de la universidad. Una última duda, conoces donde esta la API para saber editar los campos de la url? para sacar un dia concreto. Cambiando solamente range a lo mejor son muchos datos. Gracias.

Comment: No he encontrado donde está documentada. Probablemente no lo esté... Esa URL la encontré por ahí en un post. En [este repositorio git](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download) hay un programa python para leer datos históricos de finanzas de Yahoo, en formato csv. De la URL que usan en ese sitio he podido ver que hay unos parámetros llamados `period1` y `period2` que sirven para especificar el _timestamp_ de inicio y fin, respectivamete, de los datos solicitados. He probado a añadir esos parámetros a la URL de mi respuesta y ¡funcionó! Pero un día cualquiera lo cierran...

Comment: @ADRIANVAZQUEZROMERO Igual también te interesa [este notebook](https://github.com/sjev/trading-with-python/blob/master/scratch/get_yahoo_data.ipynb)